# C# WPF Localization - Ignoring other cultures and loading default Resources

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to localize my app, I've created several `Resources.[culture].resx` but program ignores them all and always loads default `Resources.resx`.

I have this code in App construtor (and in OnStartup event)

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

My resources are called `Resources.en-US.resx`, `Resources.cs-CZ.resx` and `Resources.resx`

Code in WPF is

```
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:WpfThermalLabelEditorApp.Properties"
Title="{x:Static p:Resources.Title}"
```

This should load en-US localization but it doesn't. Loads default. I tried to delete AssemblyInfo and even putting `<UICulture>` tags into csproj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after 2 days I've solved my problem. My solution was correct. I have no idea what was wrong but I've created a new project, moved all my data to a new one and suddenly everything worked as a charm.

Here is a few usefull links:

- [WPF localization and globalization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/wpf-globalization-and-localization-overview)
- [Localization tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/)
- [Localization tutorial 2](https://www.rhyous.com/2010/10/20/using-resources-resx-for-strings-in-a-wpf-application-a-technique-to-prepare-for-localization/)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the answer, but FWIW: I always set both `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` like so;

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(languageAbbreviation);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(languageAbbreviation);
```

And be sure to double check the abbreviation you use is the same for all references. That should fix your problem.

**EDIT1**: Make sure your resource files are set to public, the access modifier should be somewhere near the top when you're viewing the resource file. Double check this says public and rebuild. Also, to call your resource file key do so like this:

`<TextBlock xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"  Text="{x:Static local:Resource1.myname}"/>`

Where...

- "WpfApplication2" is replaced with your project name
- "Resource1" is replace with the name of your resource file (without culture id, e.g. for your case it would just be `Resources`)
- "myname" is replaced with the key you want

Comment: @Shocky I'm not 100% sure if this is the case for XAML but in html I use the razor engine to call my settings like so: `<label for="ideaSubject">@(PageText.POST_SUBJECT)</label>`. My resource file is called PageText in this case, and the key I'm accessing is POST_SUBJECT.

Comment: Still nothing. It still uses default Resources. Yes, my resources are all public, otherwise I would get errors.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem,  the solution was to clean and rebuild the project. No need to create new project.